# Python: OOP Tutorial 1: Classes and instances: How to use self?

Tags: python, class, oop, self

I try to learn about classes in Python. Currently, I use the the tutorial from Corey Schafer.

Here is what he wrote:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + "." + last + '@company.com'
emp_1 = Employee('First1', 'Last1', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('First2', 'Last2', 60000)
print(emp_1.email)
print(emp_2.email)
```

My question is: Why he did not use **self** also here: self.email = **self**.first + "." + **self**.last + '@company.com'

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = self.first + "." + self.last + '@company.com'
emp_1 = Employee('First1', 'Last1', 50000)
emp_2 = Employee('First2', 'Last2', 60000)
print(emp_1.email)
print(emp_2.email)
```

The output is identical in the both ways.

Comment: They're just the same, as `self.first = first`, so it makes absolutely no difference, except for a few more letters to type.

Comment: `self` is just the name (though a conventional one) for the first parameter to `__init__`. `Employee(...)`, during its execution, creates an instance then passes it to `Employee.__init__` as the first argument.

Comment: `self.first` and `first` have the same value, but there's no need to go through an attribute lookup if you have a local variable you can use instead.

Comment: You still have access to `first` and `last` variables and you know that they are the same thing as `self.first` and `self.last` at this point. If you wanted to calculate email in a function that doesn't have access to that `first` variable, you would have to use `self.first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference if u use `self.first` or `first` inside the `__init__` method since `self.first` also points to the same variable, viz, `first`.
Making a variable an attribute of `self` just makes it an instance variable and allows u to access it anywhere inside your class